# How to force all read workers consume fifo data?

Tags: bash, mkfifo

Producer:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                   

/bin/rm ./queue
/usr/bin/mkfifo ./queue

./work.sh &
./work.sh &
./work.sh &
./work.sh &

for i in {1..100};do
    echo "1" > ./queue
done


wait
echo "FINISHED"
```

Consumer work.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                   

while read line
do
    echo "$line $BASHPID"
done < ./queue
echo "FINISHED"
```

Usually only 3 workers consume data. 4th is blocked in reading fifo(open syscall), it gets no data at all. If I change

```
for i in {1..100};do
```

to

```
for i in {1..1000};do
```

all read workers consume data.
How to force all read workers to consume data?

Comment: ? Are there any data lost? You want to force that all workers consume at least one packet of data? What do you want to "force"?

Comment: nothing lost. I want all my 4 workers to do actual job. I suspect buffering is the issue

Comment: the job is `echo "$line $BASHPID"` - give them some real work, like `sleep 1`.